# MS Access - How do i use a table for a data type

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

Hi i am creating a contacts database and i want to use a create a cities table that i can use for the people table in the City field. How do i do this?

**City table:**

```
ID | City 
--------------
1 | Wellington
2 | Auckland
3 | Christchurch
```

People Table Design

- Field Name: City
- Data Type: Short Text
- Display Control: Combobox
- Row Source Type: Table/Query
- Row Source: City

These are my table design for the field City, but it is only showing the ID numbers in the combobox

Answer (score 1):

I really am against the concept of Lookups in table. So I would suggest you to have a read of "[The Evils of Lookup](http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm)" before you proceed.

The problem is because you have used a table name as the RowSource. You need t modify some of the properties of the Field. In the lookup tab, change the **Column Count** to **2**, **Column Width** to **0cm;2.04cm**. Probably RowSource to

```
SELECT ID, City FROM City;
```